# Preemptive authentication with OkHttpClient without ProxyServer

Tags: okhttp

As per https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/ , I think preemptive authentication can happen only if we have proxy server.

We have one resource/origin server which authorises clients with Oauth tokens.

We have implemented authorisation OkHttp Authenticator https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html . However, the client always makes a request without authorisation headers and then adds it. Can we use authenticator and still supply authorisation header to our resource server in a single request ? We can predict the challenge. However, not sure if it's possible to avoid a request to server without authorisation headers.

We are able to use the interceptor to add headers preemptively.

Is it possible to use Authenticator and add headers preemptively without a proxy server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Interceptor to implement preemptive authentication.  This gives you full flexibility.

You are right that purely using Authenticator, while always be done in response to the failed 401.

Hence libraries like [okhttp-digest](https://github.com/rburgst/okhttp-digest/) cache the authentication method to implement preemptively.

https://github.com/rburgst/okhttp-digest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/burgstaller/okhttp/AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.java

Comment: I see this library still uses an interceptor to add headers. However, this confirms my understanding.Thank you very much for confirmation.